# Kendo UI Grid Tabstrip - How to view details in 2nd tabs with custom button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-tabstrip

I had this demo [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/iRobiSAw) that contains tab1 and tab2. What I want to achieve when clicked on custom button "`View Details`", data's on selected row will display is tab2. Anyone can help me how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

[demo in dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/iRobiSAw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you are after: https://dojo.telerik.com/iRobiSAw/2

All I have done is obtained the `dataItem` for the row selected and then bound this to a new `ObservableObject` to the second tab.

```
 var vm = new kendo.data.ObservableObject( this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr")));
   //Added console log just to show the object has been obtained. 
  console.log(vm); 

  kendo.bind($('#grid2'), vm);
```

I haven't wired up the save button so the data doesn't persist back to the original datasource but I am sure this would be doing a save back to the server where you would be refreshing the datasource that sits under the first grid.

Comment: Thank you, yes  you're right about the save button.